# MVC - does the view know the controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, model-view-controller

I'm currently refactoring my app to be sure the it's MVC compliant.
I would like to split the controller (MyController which extends UIController) and the view (HomeView which extends UIView) I set the view in myController using

```
self.view = [[HomeView alloc] init];
```

When I push an UIButton, a method is called in the view, and in this method I would like to call a method from the controller.

In my view

```
[zenModeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchZenMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

...

```
- (void) touchZenMode:(id) sender {
   [myController playZenMode];
}
```

But having a reference to the controller in the view is really a bad practice isn't it ?

**EDIT :**

So in my UIViewController I've made this :

```
- (id) init {
    HomeView* myHomeView = [[HomeView alloc] init];
    [myHomeView.arcadeModeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchArcadeMode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.view = myHomeView;
    return self;
}
```

is that correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view talking to your controller is no problem, as outlined by some answers here. E.g. a text field can notify its controller via the defined delegate methods.

However, your design is still seriously flawed. Your view has absolutely no business handling a button press itself. Your intuition that the view should not know about its controller is correct.

Your **controller** should know about the button and how to react to it being tapped. That's why a controller has button `IBOutlet`s to tell the button to e.g. change its title or enabled state. And it has button handlers to react to UI events. It is the controller's job to handle this logic. It is the view's job to display the title, gray out or send a tap event back to the controller.

The only code you should put into a view is basically how to draw itself. Everything that *cannot* be handled by a controller.

Comment: Thanks, but the button has to be drawn too, so I have to leave it in the view right ?

Comment: Right. Create and configure the button in the controller. Remember, the controller controls the view. -- But your edit is wrong. in `init` you have to call `[[super alloc] init]` to create `self`.

Comment: yes you're right, I should call the parent constructor which is UIViewController but it seems that self = [[super alloc] init]; triggers the error "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'alloc' any clues ?

Comment: [super init] works, it that correct ? (without alloc, I guess it's self allocated ?)

Comment: Yes, you do not alloc in the init method. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea of the MVC pattern, as used in Cocoa Touch:

[image: Cocoa version of MVC as a compound design pattern]

As described here: [The Model-View-Controller Design Pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1)

What you want to achieve, is a form of loose-, even blind maybe, coupling. By using protocols (for delegation mechanism), a `View` only knows that there is an object that adopts a specific protocol, it can 'talk' to.

Take the `UITableView` for instance. It does not need to know that there is a certain type of `UIViewController` that helps it gather data, but only that there is an object that adopts the `UITableViewDatasourceDelegate` and/or `UITableViewDelegate`; that object can be of any type.

In your edit, you use the target-action mechanism, which is another way of achieving loose-coupling. You set up the connection at runtime; your View does not know your Controller. Therefor: correct, *apart from the comment @Mundi made about your `init` implementation being incomplete*.

Answer (score 0):

The view needs some way to communicate things back to the controller, ask it questions about what to do next, etc. So it's perfectly fine for the view to know something about the controller.

Some of the built-in views, like UITextField, define protocols they use to tell their delegate about what's going on, or ask it to do something. You typically implement the protocol in your controller. That way the view doesn't really know much about the controller, just enough to communicate. That makes your view more generic and reusable.

What you want to avoid is for your view to have direct links to your *model*. The role of the controller is to mediate between the view and the model. You should be able to completely change how the view is implemented without touching the model, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that method in a protocol in your view's interface:

```
@protocol MyViewDelegateProtocol <NSObject>
    -(void)myMethod;
@end
```

- you put a new property of NSObject type called delegate in your view.
- you make your view controller comply to that protocol and when it inits the view assign the delegate property to self.
- you implement myMethod in your view controller implementation.
- and now you just call [delegate myMethod] from your view whenever you need it.